# Excel VBA - issue deleting row/col from incorrect workbook

Tags: excel, vba, delete-row

This code copies data from a worksheet and pastes data into a test.csv file. If the test.csv is closed then it opens it and pastes
data into it. If it is already open then just pastes data into it. Upto this step, process works fine. After the data is pasted 
into test.csv, I need to delete rows with first column with value 'Old'. And then delete entire Col "A".

Here is the challenge I am facing. If the test.csv is closed, the macro opens it, pastes the data and then does the rows and col delete, and works as expected
, however, if the test.csv is already open, then it pastes the values as it is supposed to, but deleting row and col it does in
the main worksheet. I tried putting Delete code in **With** block but does not help. Please suggest!

```
Sub Macro()
    Dim LR As Long, PR As Long, X As Long, MyCopyRange, MyPasteRange
    Dim wb, myData As Workbook, shtPaste As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
     'open target csv file if not already opened
    If CheckFileIsOpen("test.csv") = False Then
        Set myData = Workbooks.Open(strFinalizedForBulkImport & "test.csv")
    Else
        Set myData = Workbooks("test.csv")
    End If
    Set shtPaste = myData.Sheets("test")
    shtPaste.UsedRange.Clear

   With wb.Sheets("Report Grp")

        LR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        MyCopyRange = Array("A4:A" & LR, "B4:B" & LR, "C4:C" & LR, "D4:D" & LR) 'Put ranges in an array
        MyPasteRange = Array("A1", "B1", "C1", "D1")



        If LR > 1 Then
            j = 0
            For X = LBound(MyCopyRange) To UBound(MyCopyRange) 'Loop the array copying and pasting based on element in the array
                .Range(MyCopyRange(j)).Copy
                 shtPaste.Range(MyPasteRange(j)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                j = j + 1
            Next

        Else
            Range("A1") = "No Data Found"
        End If

    End With

'Problem here, when trying to delete row with "Old" in Col "A" and finally Col "A" delete -
        With wb.Sheets("test")
            For LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
                If Range("A" & LR).Value = "Old" Then
                    Rows(LR).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            Next LR
            Columns("A").Delete Shift:=xlShiftToLeft
        End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If wb.sheets("test") is not the active sheet, you need to qualify `.Columns("A").Delete Shift:=xlShiftToLeft` with a period

Comment: BTW wb is dimmed as a variant, now a workbook. It should be `Dim wb as workbook, myData As Workbook`

Answer (score 1):

When using `with` anything in relation to that sheet need to be qualified with a period

```
With wb.Sheets("test")
    For LR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If .Range("A" & LR).Value = "Old" Then
            .Rows(LR).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next LR
    .Columns("A").Delete Shift:=xlShiftToLeft
End With
```

Comment: I made suggested changes but now while debugging code looks fine but does not delete row/col in either case - meaning regardless if the csv is open or closed. I think because -  Set wb = ThisWorkbook , while I am trying to delete in the csv. Any suggestions?

Comment: redefined TR for csv

Comment: The idea of the sample code was to show you that the ranges were not qualified to the desired sheet.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to qualifying all ranges and other sheet-dependent objects like @Davesexcel already posted, you should `Set wb = ActiveWorkbook` instead of `Set wb = ThisWorkbook`. The latter refers to the workbook the macro is stored in whereas you probably intend to use the active workbook.

For debugging, start the VBA editor (ALT+F11) and set a breakpoint on the first line of the delete loop. Check the name of the workbook `wb` refers to ("?wb.name").  Make the comparison case-independent by using `If UCase(.Range("A" & LR).Value) = "OLD" Then`.
If you single step one loop you will see why nothing is deleted.